# React-Leaflet map is not rendering data on map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, react-leaflet

> Props coming from **App.js** like below

```
<div className="app__maps">
  <h3>I am map</h3>
  <Map countries={mapCountries} center={mapCenter} zoom={mapZoom} />
</div>
```

> **Map.js** code as follows, Data is fine but inside showDataOnMap() is not adding circle in MapContainer

```
import React from "react";
import "./Map.css";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, Circle } from "react-leaflet";

const casesTypeColors = {
  cases: { hex: "#cc1034", multiplier: 800, },
  recovered: {hex: "#7dd71d", multiplier: 1200, },
  death: { hex: "#fb4443", multiplier: 2000, },
}; 
const showDataOnMap = (data, casesType = "cases") => {
  data.map((country) => {
    <Circle
      center={[country.countryInfo.lat, country.countryInfo.long]}
      fillOpacity={0.4}
      color={casesTypeColors[casesType].hex}
      fillColor={casesTypeColors[casesType].hex}
      radius={
        Math.sqrt(country[casesType]) * casesTypeColors[casesType].multiplier
      }
    >
      <Popup>
        <h4>I am popup</h4>
      </Popup>
    </Circle>;
  });
};

function Map({ countries, casesType, center, zoom }) {
  return (
    <div className="map">
      <MapContainer
        center={center}
        zoom={zoom}
        doubleClickZoom={true}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />

        {showDataOnMap(countries, casesType)}
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

> **Data Generating like below data image**

[image]

> please help why data is not rendering on my map?
> result should be like below image

[image]

Comment: Please consider using https://codesandbox.io/ to provide an example we can work on and better help with your issue

Comment: Thanks @MoaazBhnas, Here is the sandbox for you guys.
https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-stallman-38npv?file=/src/Map.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not **returning** anything inside `showDataOnMap` that is the reason you do not see any circles. Use return keyword or don't use curly braces to return the result of the loop and the function itself.

```
const showDataOnMap = (data, casesType = "cases") => {
  return data.map((country) => {
    return <Circle
      center={[country.countryInfo.lat, country.countryInfo.long]}
      fillOpacity={0.4}
      color={casesTypeColors[casesType].hex}
      fillColor={casesTypeColors[casesType].hex}
      radius={
        Math.sqrt(country[casesType]) * casesTypeColors[casesType].multiplier
      }
    >
      <Popup>
        <h4>I am popup</h4>
      </Popup>
    </Circle>;
  });
};
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-v3x-map-is-not-rendering-data-on-map-e54v7)

Comment: Thanks for your help, It is working on sendbox, why not working in local server?

Comment: I am not sure about that since I do not have access to that local server. Maybe webpack configuration or any configuration in general. It could be anything

Comment: is there any way to get collaborate in vs code, to see what actually happening in my code?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I fix it on local server. It was my mistake on local.